# What happened to Apple made server racks?

Tags: xserve

Simply the question is, what happened to the the Apple made server racks? It is very disappointing to see Apple doesn't support the back-end hardware since 2009. I know there is a Server Mini, and OSX server, but lets face it, we want a professional and fast hardware to backup OSX Server.

Comment: Close this: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:

Apple discontinued them in 2010.

According to other sources sales were poor, and Steve Jobs responded to their inquiry:

> Hardly anyone was buying them.
>
> Sent from my iPhone

source: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1045345